# data not being fetched from resouce.query of angular js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am new to angular and rails.  I am trying to fetch the user from db and want to show it over screen as index page. I am able to fetch the data in the rails controller, but getting empty in angular controller

angular controller:

```
app = angular.module("userApp", ["ngResource"])
app.controller("userController", function($scope, $resource, $http){
User = $resource('/users', {}, {query: {method: "GET", isArray: true}}) 
    $scope.users = User.query()
    alert($scope.users)
});
```

Rails controller:
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html

```
def index
@user = User.all
@user.each do |u|
    puts u.name
end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
end
end
```

I am getter $scope.users as empty.
Please help me out on this.

Thanks,
JK

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the resource before it is ready. Use the success callback instead

```
... 
app.controller("userController", function($scope, $resource, $http){
 ... 
   User.query({}, function(data){
      $scope.users = data;
      alert($scope.users)
   })  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this way. Still I am not getting any data. More over alert message is not coming.